# Group numbers coming incorrectly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a address matching algorithm which compares the pincodes of the addresses of a customer id with that of the other customer id and creates a list of the customer ids having similar kind of addresses. Next i assign a particular group number to each of the lists of customer ids. But the problem is most of the list of customer ids are grouped under the proper group number but some ids are grouped under different numbers even though they have the same addresses

I have made the address matching script and found the customer ids having similar address and put them in a list and assigned a group number to each of the lists. But the group numbers are correct for some ids and some ids even after having similar addresses and being in the same list are having different group numbers

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

def how_similar(address,address_list):

    address = address.strip()
    address1_split = address.split(" ")
    pinCode_address1 = address1_split[-1]
    area_address1 = " ".join(address1_split[:-1])

    matched_address = []

    for add in address_list:
        score = 0
        add = add.strip()
        address2_split = add.split(" ")
        pinCode_address2 = address2_split[-1]
        area_address2 = " ".join(address2_split[:-1])


        area_score = fuzz.token_set_ratio(area_address1,area_address2)

        score+=area_score

        if score>= 90 :
            matched_address.append(add)


    return matched_address
```

## Getting the DataFrame as the parameter

```
def pat_match(df):

    # Getting the column values of id and address in seprate list
    id = df['COD_CUST_ID'].values.tolist()
    address = df['ADDRESS'].values.tolist()

    # Creating a new column with name 'Ids'
    df['Ids'] = ""
    length01=len(id)

    for y in range(0,length01):
        #print(y)
        # The mathched address Id will will be appended in a list for every address
        matched_ids = []

        # Calculating list of address with match percentage more than 80%
        #score=process.extractBests(address[y],address,score_cutoff=80)

        score= how_similar(address[y],address)


        # Iterating over every address returned by score one by one
        for matched_address in score:
            # Getting Customer_ID of every Address
            get = df['COD_CUST_ID'][df['ADDRESS']==matched_address].tolist()
            # Appending the Id into a list
            if get not in matched_ids:
                matched_ids.append(get)


        # Finally Appending the list of matched ID to the column
        df['Ids'][df['COD_CUST_ID']==id[y]] = str(matched_ids)
```

#################### Code for grouping

```
   # Creating a new column with name 'Group' and 'Matched'
    df['group'] = ""
    df['Matched'] = ""
    grouped_customers = []

    Group_count = 1
    for i in range(length01):

        try:

            id_list = df['Ids'][i]
            new_list = id_list[1:-1]

            new_list=new_list.replace('[','')
            new_list=new_list.replace(']','')

            new_list = new_list.split(',')
            new_list = [int(x) for x in new_list]
            #print(new_list)
       # print(i)
            for id in new_list:

                if id not in grouped_customers:

                    df['group'][df['COD_CUST_ID'] == id] = Group_count
                    df['Matched'][df['COD_CUST_ID'] == id] = id

                    grouped_customers.append(id)

                    if id == new_list[-1]:
                        Group_count+=1

        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

    df.to_csv('match_score_8.csv',sep=',',index=None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = pd.read_csv('address.csv')
    pat_match(data)
```

Suppose i have a output as

```
COD_CUST_ID         ADDRESS                                       Ids              group     Matched
23656386    VPO- DHANGER KHER ABOHAR  152116    [[23656386], [23656388, 23656387]]  8   23656386
23656388    VPO- DHANGER KHERA ABOHAR  152116   [[23656386], [23656388, 23656387]]  8   23656388
23656387    VPO- DHANGER KHERA ABOHAR  152116   [[23656386], [23656388, 23656387]]  8   23656387
```

This is the actual output required which i am getting for most of the ids. But there are a few ids in which the output is like

```
COD_CUST_ID         ADDRESS                         Ids                     group   Matched
23656887    TODAWATA KI DHANI FATEHPURA BANSA 303806    [[23656887], [23666683], [23666717, 23666721, 23666773]]    416 23656933
23666683    - - FATEHPURA BANSA 303806        [[23656980], [23656887], [23666683], [23666717, 23666721, 23666773]]  196 23666664
23666717    BANSA   303806                                  [similar list of matching ids]  151 23666717
23666721    BANSA   303806                                  [similar list of matching ids]  151 23666721
23666773    BANSA   303806                      [similar list of matching ids]  151 23666773
```

The matched ids should be in the same group